# Problems with Export XML in VS 2008

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm facing a problem.
I want to export an XML file from a datagridview in VS 2008
To do this i use the XElement like

```
New XElement("InstdAmt", SomeValue)
```

This will export to me

```
<InstdAmt>SomeValue</InstdAmt>
```

In my case i want to export THIS

```
<InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">SomeValue</InstdAmt>
```

How can i do this?
Hope you understand what i want because my English is not very good :(

Comment: What is "SomeValue"?

Comment: use XAttribute to add an attribute to the node

Comment: Perfect Laserson. Thanks :)